# How to use pg_dump correctly to replicate my local database to a remote server

Tags: sql, postgresql, cloud-hosting

I'm struggling trying to move my local postgres db to my Digital Ocean cluster. I want to make my new remote server my main dB, hence pass all roles and privilege's. I read the `pg_dump` doc and still couldn't figure out how to resolve my issue. These are my commands below:

create the dump file:

```
pg_dump -U postgres --no-owner sb > dump_file
```

connect to remote server from DO and move dB:

```
pg_restore -d {MY_URI_CONNECTION} dump_file
```

The data, schema, and tables get created, but not the roles, which throws an error in my terminal:

```
ERROR:  role "admin" does not exist
ERROR:  role "admin" does not exist
ERROR:  role "web_anon" does not exist
WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
REVOKE
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
GRANT
ERROR:  role "web_anon" does not exist
ERROR:  role "web_anon" does not exist
ERROR:  role "web_anon" does not exist
ERROR:  role "web_anon" does not exist
ERROR:  role "web_anon" does not exist
ERROR:  must be member of role "postgres"
ERROR:  role "USER" does not exist
```

I've tried multiple ways to migrate my dB, but I keep running into the same error. How can I migrate all of my dB including roles and privilege's, overcoming my error above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pg_dumpall -g > globals_file.sql`. See here [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html). This will give you a plain text file of all globals(roles included). Restore to new cluster first with `psql -d db -U superuser -f globals_file.sql` Be aware this will dump all roles from a given cluster.

Comment: Hi Adrian, when I try to restore the global files, I see some roles were `SET` and  `CREATED`, I wasn't able to use a superuser because digital ocean doesnt support it? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/managed-postgres-clusters-pg_restore-errors-for-superuser-privileges

Comment: Yet another reason not use a managed product. Can't help you there other then to say use a product that does not inhibit you options. Personally I use Linode and a VM that I have full control over.